# jQuery: Change css background image on first click, then back to original image on next click and so forth

Tags: jquery, slide, out

I'm trying to create a slide out feedback form that switches images on each click.

The first feedback image shows "feedback +". I want users to click on this, feedback form slides out, then the image will show "feedback -" . I've already got this far, but can't figure out how to get "feedback +" to appear when users want to minimize or click it a second time.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="slide-out-div">
  <a class="handle" href="#"></a> 
  <!-- feedback form goes here -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.handle{
width:40px;
height:141px;
background-image:url(../images/feedback-plus.png);}
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(function() {
      $('.handle').click(function() {
        $(this).css('background-image', 'url(images/feedback-minus.png)');
      });
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add a class to your element who changes the background image

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(function() {
    $('.handle').click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("feedback-minus");
    });
  })
});
```

```css
.handle{
  width:40px;
  height:141px;
  background-image:url(../images/feedback-plus.png);
  color: blue;
}
.handle.feedback-minus{
  background-image:url(../images/feedback-minus.png);
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide-out-div">
  <a class="handle" href="#">Hello World</a> 
  <!-- feedback form goes here -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var backgroundIsPlus = true;

        $('.handle').click(function() {
            if (backgroundIsPlus) {
                $(this).css('background-image', 'url(images/feedback-minus.png)');
            }
            else {
                $(this).css('background-image', 'url(images/feedback-plus.png)');
            }
            backgroundIsPlus = !backgroundIsPlus;
        });
    })
</script>
```